# Active Directory Get-ADUser script

Tags: powershell

Everyday I need to check for a lot of users -Properties and Member of groups from Active Directory.

So, right now I'm using Powershell's command Get-ADUser *username* -Properties
It's taken me a lot of time because I'm typing that command in Powershell manually every time.

Is there a solution, a script or an application, which can help me to automate this process? Something like a form where I will put only the username then that script will run this command automatically?

For example:

Username: *username* ENTER

then the script will run 
Get-ADUser *username* -Properties

Result:

User Properties

---

no code, i need a script

---

Comment: SF is no coding service. What have you tried so far.

Comment: Please add a sample command (that you usually manually type in) with the concerned properties  to the question.

Comment: for example : Get-ADUser *username* -Properties PasswordLastSet or LastLogonDate

Comment: @DarkSoul - always add your code to your Original Post so that it will be seen by everyone who tries to help.[*grin*] ///// you are unlikely to get much help here since **_you have not bothered to read the rules - or to even use a simple net search to find any of the MULTITUDE of scripts that do what you ask AND are online with full articles to help understand them_**.

Comment: If the properties aren't predefined either ("*PasswordLastSet **or** LastLogonDate*"), what will be the use of a script? Instead of typing `Get-ADUser username -Properties` you will end up with typing something like `CustomScript username -Properties`. Please be more specific in what you really expect or are you actually looking for an user interface like [ADUC (Active Directory Users and Computers](https://www.varonis.com/blog/active-directory-users-and-computers/)?

Comment: I need something like this CustomScript username where CustomScript is that command in Powershell [Get -ADUser username -Properties]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are asking... but I'd say make a function and store it in your profile.ps1.

Something simple like:

```
Function Check-ADUser($Username){
    $Properties = "whatever properties you want"
    Get-ADUser $username -Properties * | Select $Properties
}
```

Then you just type "Check-ADUser Username"

Answer (score 0):

Powershell is full of shortcuts.  There's tab completion on everything.  "get-adu" and press tab.  "-pr" and press tab.  Or you can just use "-pr", since it's unique enough.  Also you can make an alias for get-aduser, let's say "ga".  And put it in your $profile.  Or you can make a function, like another answer addresses.  Or you can type "aduser" instead of "get-aduser", since it begins with "get".

```
new-alias ga get-aduser
ga user1 -pr *
```